# How to do proper jQuery user authentication with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, curl

I am stymied by a simple exercise. I have a REST api server that requires user authentication. A cURL command shows it working:

```
curl -k --user tyrion@yahoo.ca:Lannister https://miramar21.com/tut_server/default/api/verify/person/james.bond@outlook.com/Prometheus
```

To do this from jQuery, then, should be simple:

```
$.ajax
({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://miramar21.com/tut_server/default/api/verify/person/james.bond@outlook.com/Prometheus",
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("tyrion@yahoo.ca:Lannister")
  },
  success: function (dta){
    alert(JSON.stringify(dta));
  }
});
```

However, I get this error:

OPTIONS https://miramar21.com/tut_server/default/api/verify/person/james.bond@outlook.com/Prometheus 400 (BAD REQUEST)

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://miramar21.com/tut_server/default/api/verify/person/james.bond@outlook.com/Prometheus. Invalid HTTP status code 400

I tried using beforeSend instead of headers:

```
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic "+btoa("tyrion@yahoo.ca:Lannister"));
  },
```

But I get the same outcome. The cURL command proves that the login credentials are correct, so why is jQuery choking???

Comment: Do not share your credentials online!

Comment: @Vohuman
This is just a demo exercise. No harm in revealing the credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The short answer :**
The solution to the issue is to allow OPTIONS method at you server end point by setting 
**Access-Control-Allow-Methods** to **POST, GET, OPTIONS**. You can add more methods too. Once you do this, The Authorized AJAX calls you are making from browsers will start working normally. Checkout [this link](http://enable-cors.org/server.html), it has samples in many languages for allowing specific HTTP request methods on your server side.

**The one which is detailed:**
There is no issue with the AJAX request you are making, the problem is at the URL end-point. The server side end point of the URL you are trying to make request to, doesn't support/allow the HTTP preflight **OPTIONS** method. 
jQuery is not choking here, but the browser is intercepting the request and making a preflighted request first for maybe security reasons. All the browsers have made the preflight requests mandatory for NON-SIMPLE Cross Domain server/ajax requests. And your request being a cross domain request uses **OPTIONS** method first to check whether other methods like **GET, POST, DELETE etc.** are accessible on server or not.
Now, we also see that when the same request is made using **CURL**, passes without errors. It happens because CURL does not make a preflight request and directly calls **GET** method which is allowed on your server URL end point. You can make a preflighted request with this CURL command(*which shows the request being cross-origin and also has the OPTIONS method enabled*):

```
curl -v -H "Origin: http://127.0.0.1" -X OPTIONS -k --user tyrion@yahoo.ca:Lannister https://miramar21.com/tut_server/default/api/verify/person/james.bond@outlook.com/Prometheus
```

You will get a response similar to what you are getting in the browser, i.e, a **404 BAD REQUEST** error.

Make the same request with GET method:

```
curl -v -H "Origin: http://127.0.0.1" -X GET -k --user tyrion@yahoo.ca:Lannister https://miramar21.com/tut_server/default/api/verify/person/james.bond@outlook.com/Prometheus
```

And, you will see that the response is what you expected.

An OPTIONS request doesn't need Authorization headers, so to check whether any method is supported by your server URL end-point, you need to run CURL requests similar to the ones below:

1. `curl -X OPTIONS -v https://miramar21.com/tut_server/default/api/verify/person/james.bond@outlook.com/Prometheus` : This **will** give "method not supported" message.
2. `curl -X GET -v https://miramar21.com/tut_server/default/api/verify/person/james.bond@outlook.com/Prometheus` : This **won't** give the "method not supported" message.

So, enabling/allowing the OPTIONS request method in your server side script could be a solution to this problem.

Checkout this link to get a good idea about the Preflighted requests: [MDN Access Control CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).
I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Now that I understand what the h*ll is going on, I've decided to do all my own user authorization via POST. It's much simpler!

Comment: Thanks! .. even if you are going to use POST for authorization, you might need to allow OPTIONS request on your side. I guess the preflight requests will appear even with POST.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the username and password fields

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://miramar21.com/tut_server/default/api/verify/person/james.bond@outlook.com/Prometheus",
  dataType: 'json',
  username: 'tyrion@yahoo.ca',
  password: 'Lannister',
  success: function (dta){
    alert(JSON.stringify(dta));
  }
});
```

Comment: I also tried using the username and password fields, too. Although I get no errors, it fails to match credentials.